# Do I need to convert a resource bundle to a map to access the values or can I directly use the bundle?

Tags: java, internationalization

Not being too familiar with Java, I may be doing something redundant or unnecessary.  I am getting a `ResourceBundle` and then looking to convert it to a `Map` and then using values from the map.

This is what I am trying to do ...

```
    try {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("filename");
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        ...
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
    Map<String, String> map = convertResourceBundleToMap (bundle);
    
    // Then else where in the code, to get a value, I do
    map.get(key);
```

Method to convert the `ResourceBundle` to `Map`:

```
    private static Map<String, String> convertResourceBundleToMap(ResourceBundle resource) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    
        Enumeration<String> keys = resource.getKeys();

        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            String value = resource.getString(key);
            map.put(key, value);
        
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Is there a downside to getting the values directly from `ResourceBundle` with a

```
resource.getString(key);
```

call?

Also, how would one do this if it were to be in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: From the documentation: '... the direct known concrete subclasses ListResourceBundle and PropertyResourceBundle are thread-safe.'

Comment: One big disadvantage of converting to a map is that you lose all internationalization features that ResourceBundle provides. ResourceBundle allows to define resources for different locales and it already handles loading the appropriate one for the users current locale. You lose all those features by your map conversion.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I am actually using it more as a properties file rather than for locales. Is there a downside to getting values directly from the ResourceBundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have some exotic use-case, you can and should use `ResourceBundle` methods directly, for the following reasons:

1. `ResourceBundle` is specifically designed to be used this way. There are also additional methods available, for example, `getStringArray()`. You would lose some of the `ResourceBundle` information if you convert it to a plain map.
2. `ResourceBundle` has additional parent-child logic (like `Properties`). It solves the defaulting problem, when not all strings are translated into every locale. This parent-child relation would be de-normalized when converting to a map.
3. Conversion to a map is an additional performance and memory overhead which doesn't bring any significant benefits.
4. `ResourceBundle` is thread safe. Default method implementations are thread safe, and the class contract requires all subclasses to be thread-safe.

---

I could think of converting a `ResourceBundle` into a map only for some unusual use-cases, like serializing the strings to JSON, or transforming the keys/values somehow.